# Get the row corresponding to the max in pandas GroupBy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

Simple DataFrame:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,2,2], 'B': [0,1,2,3], 'C': ['a','b','c','d']})
df
   A  B  C
0  1  0  a
1  1  1  b
2  2  2  c
3  2  3  d
```

I wish for every value (`groupby`) of column A, to get the value of column C, for which column B is maximum. For example for group 1 of column A, the maximum of column B is 1, so I want the value "b" of column C:

```py
   A  C
0  1  b
1  2  d
```

No need to assume column B is sorted, performance is of top priority, then elegance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check with `sort_values` +`drop_duplicates`

```
df.sort_values('B').drop_duplicates(['A'],keep='last')
Out[127]: 
   A  B  C
1  1  1  b
3  2  3  d
```

Comment: That is impressive, I had to say.

Comment: Accepting this answer as according to `timeit` it's faster than @coldspeed's by 0.0002 seconds [`np.mean(timeit.repeat("df.sort_values('B').drop_duplicates(['A'],keep='last')", number = 1, repeat = 100, globals = globals()))`]

Comment: @GioraSimchoni Thank you for the fair consideration and timings!

Comment: this is brilliant!

Answer (score 7):

```
df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: x.loc[x['B'].idxmax(), 'C'])
#    A
#1    b
#2    d
```

Use [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) to find the index where `B` is maximal, then select column `C` within that group (using a lambda-function

Answer (score 5):

Here's a little fun with `groupby` and `nlargest`:

```
(df.set_index('C')
   .groupby('A')['B']
   .nlargest(1)
   .index
   .to_frame()
   .reset_index(drop=True))

   A  C
0  1  b
1  2  d
```

---

Or, `sort_values`, `groupby`, and `last`:

```
df.sort_values('B').groupby('A')['C'].last().reset_index()

   A  C
0  1  b
1  2  d
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar solution to @Jondiedoop, but avoids the `apply`:

```
u = df.groupby('A')['B'].idxmax()

df.loc[u, ['A', 'C']].reset_index(drop=1)
```

```
   A  C
0  1  b
1  2  d
```