# panda group on set column and get corresponding max value from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My data is as follow :

```py
 set_name |  cases | label

0 {a,b,c}    7        'a b c'
1 {j,i,a}    2        'j i a'
2 {a,c}      1        'a c'
3 {b,c,a}    2        'b c a'
```

i would like to groupby on set_name with sum on cases . but - i need the label to correspond to the row with max cases . so the output will look like :

```py
 set_name |  cases | label

0 {a,b,c}    9        'a b c'
1 {j,i,a}    2        'j i a'
2 {a,c}      1        'a c'
```

Since both {a,b,c} and {b,c,a} are equal (they are set) i want to sum them up.
i've tried using the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54334767/get-the-row-corresponding-to-the-max-in-pandas-groupby) but since groupby cant work on sets i cant proceed with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Becuase `set`s are unhashable one possible solution is use `frozenset`s and aggregate by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
df1 = (df.sort_values(by='cases', ascending=False)
         .groupby(df['set_name'].apply(frozenset))
         .agg({'set_name': 'first',
               'cases':'sum',
               'label':'first'})
         .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df1)
    set_name  cases  label
0  {a, c, b}      9  a b c
1  {i, j, a}      2  j i a
2     {a, c}      1    a c
```

Comment: i think i need to add df.sort_values(by='cases', ascending=False) before so the 'first" in agg will take the label correspond to the one with the max cases

Answer (score 1):

```
(
    df.sort_values(by='cases', ascending=False)
    .groupby(df.set_name.apply(sorted).apply(str))
    .agg(set_name=('set_name', 'first'),
         cases=('cases', 'sum'),
         lalbel=('label', 'first'),
        )
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```